# How do I map multiple xml attributes to a single c# property on deserialization?

Tags: c#, xml, attributes, deserialization, linq-to-xml

I can't use the `[XmlChoiceIdentifier]` because multiple`[XmlAttribute]` isn't allowed unlike `[XmlElement]`. The standard solution to create multiple properties for each attribute name is unwieldy in my situation. It will result in a bloated file and many null checks. Can't change the xml I'm working with. Small example of my issue below.

```
<Animal blooded="warm"> <!--The attribute can be "blooded", "bloodtype", etc.-->
    <Horse>Jack</Horse>
    <Chicken>Charlie</Chicken>
</Animal>
```

```
[Serializable]
public partial class Animal
{
    public string Horse { get; set; }

    public string Chicken { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("blooded")]
    public string BloodKind { get; set; }
}
```

I want to write

```
    [XmlAttribute("blooded")]
    [XmlAttribute("bloodtype")] // <------ trying to do this, any work around?
    public string BloodKind { get; set; }
```

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer( typeof(Animal) );
        using Stream reader = new FileStream( "data.xml", FileMode.Open );
        Animal animal = (Animal)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

        Console.WriteLine(animal.BloodKind);
    }

}
```

Comment: There is not a a chance you could run an xslt-transformation before deserializing?

Comment: That would add a layer complexity. Though I'm not too familiar with xslt transforms, I'm not sure that'd help here unfortunately.

Comment: Note: you don't need `[Serializable]` for `XmlSerializer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
[XmlAttribute("blooded")]
public string Blooded
{
    get => BloodKind;
    set => BloodKind = value;
}
public bool ShouldSerializeBlooded() => false;

[XmlAttribute("bloodtype")]
public string BloodKind { get; set; }
```

Basically, we've made `Blooded` a pass-thru proxy to `BloodKind`, and only `BloodKind` is considered for serialization.

Comment: Thanks, is the boolean function for convenience for serializing this object? It doesn't appear like it's needed for deserializing.

Comment: @Hysperr yes; that stops us getting both attributes when we serialize; if you don't need to worry about that: omit it. Likewise, if you need to track *which specific* attribute deserialized (and retain that) , you'd need to make it more complex